# How to get org mode attached images visible with 'org-toggle-inline-images'?

Tags: org-mode, inline-image, org-attach

`org-attach-method` `'cp`

Tryed
`org-attach-store-link-p` `'attached`

```
[[attachment:picture.jpg][picture.jpg]]
```

and `org-attach-store-link-p` `'file`

```
[[file:data/xx/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/picture.jpg][picture.jpg]]
```

Also attempted:

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist '(("attachment" . org-attach-expand-links)))
```

Which produces:

```
Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

Is there a (built-in) solution what would satisfy this:

```
(org-display-inline-images &optional INCLUDE-LINKED REFRESH BEG END)

Display inline images.

An inline image is a link which follows either of these
conventions:

  1. Its path is a file with an extension matching return value
     from ‘image-file-name-regexp’ and it has no contents.

  2. Its description consists in a single link of the previous
     type.  In this case, that link must be a well-formed plain
     or angle link, i.e., it must have an explicit "file" type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first method, i.e. `(setq org-attach-store-link-p 'attached)`, attach the image with `C-c C-a` as usual, insert an `attachment` link with `C-c C-l`, but *make sure that the description is empty*: do not accept the default description that `C-c C-l` gives you; just delete the whole thing and give it an empty description. That will make the link conform to case `1.` in the documentation you quote and it will allow `C-c C-x C-v` (i.e. `org-toggle-inline-images`) to inline the image (assuming of course that the image type is supported by your Emacs).

Do `M-: (info "(org)Images")` to view the relevant section of the manual (or equivalently [Images](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images.html) in the online manual) where it says:

> An image is a link to an image file(1) that *does not have a
> description part*

(emphasis added)

Alternatively, for case 2. you can make the description identical to the link, i.e add the string `attachment:` when `C-c C-l` prompts you for the description since the default description is the filename. So instead of adding a link like this:

```
[[attachment:filename.jpg]]
```

you add a link like this:

```
[[attachment:filename.jpg][attachment:filename.jpg]]
```

where the description is identical to the link. That also allows `C-c C-x C-v` to display the image inline, but it hardly seems worth the bother: it is easier to get rid of the description than add a link type and, visually, the two links appear the same in the Org mode buffer.

EDIT: In a comment the OP says that `attachment` links don't work, they have to be `file` links instead. That is wrong: `attachment` links *and* `file` links both work and in the same way, although attachment links are more convenient since you don't have to know the full pathname of the attachment directory (and when you do `C-c C-a`, an attachment link is added to `org-stored-links` for `C-c C-l` to insert into the Org mode file).

Here is a test file that I created to demonstrate:

```org
* test of attachment links for inline display of images                                                         :ATTACH:
:PROPERTIES:
:ID:       9de6b294-08b2-424a-8ed7-428d88b95594
:END:

Attachment link with no description:
[[attachment:tascam.jpg]]

Attachment link with a description that is *not* identical with the link:
[[attachment:tascam.jpg][some image]]

Attachment link with a description that is identical to the link:
[[attachment:tascam.jpg][attachment:tascam.jpg]]

File link to the same file with no description:
[[file:data/9d/e6b294-08b2-424a-8ed7-428d88b95594/tascam.jpg]]

File link to the same file with a description that is **not* identical with the link:
[[file:data/9d/e6b294-08b2-424a-8ed7-428d88b95594/tascam.jpg][Some image]]

File link to the same file with a description that is identical with the link:
[[file:data/9d/e6b294-08b2-424a-8ed7-428d88b95594/tascam.jpg][file:data/9d/e6b294-08b2-424a-8ed7-428d88b95594/tascam.jpg]]
```

and here's a screenshot after I do `C-c C-x C-v` to toggle inline images:

[image]

For both `attachment` and `file` links, the link with no description and the link with a description that is identical to the link referent properly inline the image. In both cases, the link with a description that is different from the link referent does not inline the image.

Comment: Thanks ! To make this answer complete, according to case 2. in the quoted document, what descriptions is allowed to inline the image ?

Comment: See the added paragraph.

Comment: It was meant for the readers of this topic. Anyway's I try do this here: `[[file:data/xx/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/picture.jpg][file:data/xx/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/picture.jpg]]` works, but this not `[[attachment:picture.jpg][file:data/xx/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/picture.jpg]]`

Comment: ... which is what I said: the link and the description have to be identical.

Comment: So are you saying this answer no longer answers your question? I'm not sure why you withdrew your acceptance - could you please enlighten me?

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't seen your edit. But nevertheless `[[attachment:filename.jpg][attachment:filename.jpg]]` doesn't work, seemingly they both have to be `file` type. My aim was also to see, if it is also possible to use thumbnail image for attached image ? On "Images in HTML export" chapter is see that `[[file:highres.jpg][file:thumb.jpg]]` is available for html export backend.

Comment: You are doing something wrong - see my edit with my test code. As for thumbnails, that's not part of your question: please ask it in a new question.